# "Electromagnetic" Black Hole

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, black-holes

Suppose you take a large arbitrary positive electric charge $Q$.
Then, given a distance $r$, we can calculate the escape velocity $v$ necessary for an electron to escape the positive charge (just like a rocket trying to escape Earth's gravity).

1. Could this escape velocity be equal or greater to $c$?
2. Would this create a space from which no negative charge can escape? A sort of "black hole" for negatively charged particles?
3. Does this mean no positively charged particle could enter this space? Is this a sort of "white hole" for positively charged particles?
4. Suppose that you "free" one of the positive charges inside. The electric force would obviously repel it incredibly strongly. I seem to remember something about that the speed of particles falling into a black hole approaches the speed of light. Would a positive particle escaping from our "white hole" appear to be moving at the speed of light, at the event horizon?

I tried to make some back-of-the-envelope calculations, but without taking relativity into consideration I don't really trust the results.

Comment: I'm thinking it's not possible, because the relativistic kinetic energy goes to infinity as the speed approaches $c$, which means that you can always escape. Unless, of course, the energy density of the field is so strong it creates an actual black hole; I don't know if that can happen.

Comment: Doesn't this argument work just as well for normal gravitational black holes?

Comment: No, because in general relativity the curvature of spacetime plays an additional role, and in fact the only role. In EM there's only forces and potential energy.

Comment: I understand that there is a qualitative difference because of gravity's role in general relativity. But I still don't see how this proves our electron can always escape.

Comment: If you take a bunch of positive charges, and you push them together, it takes a large amount of energy. If you have enough energy in a small volume, you get a black hole.

Comment: That's an interesting argument. That we would necessarily get a gravitational black hole to begin with. But I think I'll need to see some equations before I believe it.

Comment: Also, even if we require a gravitational black hole, we need to show that the electromagnetic event horizon is within the gravitational event horizon.

Comment: Hmmm... Definitely the same concept, but I think it only addresses the first question. Also, Izzhov shared a link about the calculations referencing http://www.mrelativity.net/, which is a quasi-science website.

Comment: Is the [Kerr metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) relevant here ?  It deals with charged black holes, after all.

Comment: @StephenG you mean Kerr-Newman

Comment: @AHusain Quite so.

Comment: In its current form, this is a duplicate of Stephen's link, whose negative answer introduces subtleties that render the subsequent parts ill-posed. If you rephrase the question to take those features into account then this can be reopened.

Comment: In the question StephenG provided a link to, the 'no' answer offers no calculations in support, except a link to mrelativity.net that deals with calculating escape velocities from gravity. But that website belongs to someone who believes general relativity is wrong and developed "his own" theory of relativity. If someone could actually post a legitimate calculation showing a 'no' to the first question then that would be fine...

Answer (score 0):

There are charged Black Holes, with stationary solutions known for both spherical symmetry and axial symmetry with rotation. Those may be the only stationary Black Holes (BH's) possible, by the No Hair theorems (they are for spherical symmetry if you assume a positive energy condition, and possibly other constraints, and I can't remember if also unique for rotating holes, with similar constraints)

Regardless of the uniqueness, which may be so except for scalar or maybe other quantum fields, the important thing about charged BH's is that there's a limit to how much charge they can have. If they have too much, compared to the BHBH mass, the gravitational attraction won't be enough to hold the mutually repelling charges in. It is not that a BH will break part, that can't happen, it's that they will never form with too much charge. It's been simulated and theoretically studied, and charges just don't go inside the horizon when there is too much already there.

The same is true for angular momentum. There's a limit, and if you try to drop a high angular momentum particle on a BH already at the limit, it'll just have enough angular momentum to fly off and not make it in.

See http://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/776b/chappell.pdf. The bottom line is that a BH with $m^2$ less than ($Q^2 + a^2$), in natural units and with Q the total charge and 'a' a measure of angular momentum is not possible. Some simulations verify that, but it is not fully proven. It is known that in those cases the horizons don't form, and if there is any singularity then it'd be naked singularities. The belief is that it is not possible.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  I am puzzled, can you say in a few words what the OP asked? Unless one thinks that there can be charge without mass/energy  attached?

Comment: That's very interesting, but how do we know that to setup the necessary positive charges would create a gravitational black hole to begin with?

Comment: @annav OP is clearly phrased only in terms of electromagnetic interaction. If Bob is claiming that having enough positively charge together that no negative charge can escape, then the energy density is necessarily high enough that a gravitational black hole forms (and that is a tall order conceptually, since the amount of positive charge $Q$ grows with the minimal negative charge $q$ you want it to trap; cf. the duplicate), then that's a nontrivial calculation that's currently lacking.

Comment: It all depends on the Q/m ratio, where Q is the net charge. In natural units it's my equation above, for spherical it has to be Q/m less than 1. If greater you can not compress it enough. As for positive and negative charges around, that's not necessarily a net charge and you then have to analyze subregions where there is a net charge. If a Charged BH gets oppositely charged particles thrown it it'll just absorb them, change the net charge, increase m, and stay a BH until you throw enough in to get to the limit again (Btw, Q is really the absolute value). Can't analyze it w/o BH physics,

Comment: So, if there is so little mass you want to ignore it a BH cannot form, and a charged foam ball cannot be without some other force. The question makes little sense. If there is mass the equation was already stated. And also if the charge outside a horizon is negative or positive the answers were already given including the addition of the comment. The duplicate answer back in 2013 is questionable

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  have you seen the answer to your comment by Bob